# How to work with JPA and Facade?

Tags: java, database, jpa, crud

I've a problem with JPA and Facade modell because I don't know how to use it now. I have a class called "Kandidatenstamm" (that's an enitity). For this Kandidatenstamm a Facade and Controller exist. There is also a Abstract Facade and a Abstract Controller. So what do I have to do in a bean for example, to get a object from database with id=4?

Here's my code

Abstract Facade

```
public abstract class AbstractFacade<T> {
private Class<T> entityClass;

public AbstractFacade(Class<T> entityClass) {
    this.entityClass = entityClass;
}

protected abstract EntityManager getEntityManager();

public void create(T entity) {
    getEntityManager().persist(entity);
}

public void edit(T entity) {
    getEntityManager().merge(entity);
}

public void remove(T entity) {
    getEntityManager().remove(getEntityManager().merge(entity));
}

public T find(Object id) {
    return getEntityManager().find(entityClass, id);
}

public List<T> findAll() {
    javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery cq = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
    cq.select(cq.from(entityClass));
    return getEntityManager().createQuery(cq).getResultList();
}

public List<T> findRange(int[] range) {
    javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery cq = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
    cq.select(cq.from(entityClass));
    javax.persistence.Query q = getEntityManager().createQuery(cq);
    q.setMaxResults(range[1] - range[0] + 1);
    q.setFirstResult(range[0]);
    return q.getResultList();
}

public int count() {
    javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery cq = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
    javax.persistence.criteria.Root<T> rt = cq.from(entityClass);
    cq.select(getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().count(rt));
    javax.persistence.Query q = getEntityManager().createQuery(cq);
    return ((Long) q.getSingleResult()).intValue();
}

}
```

KandidatenstammFacade

```
 @Stateless
public class KandidatenstammFacade extends AbstractFacade<Kandidatenstamm> {
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "ffswebadministrationPU")
private EntityManager em;

@Override
protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
    return em;
}

public KandidatenstammFacade() {
    super(Kandidatenstamm.class);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I've managed it myself. Only make a EJB Injection and use the Facade. Example here with "Personenstamm" (same as "Kandidatenstamm" in principle)

```
@EJB
private PersonenstammFacade personenstammFacade;

....

List <Personenstamm> personlist;
personlist = personenstammFacade.findAll();

....
//do what you want with this list
```